# Conditional display a section based on the items of the array in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the below code which should display a section only if the status is "Pending" in an all the selected items.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedAlerts.length && selectedStatus[0] === 'PENDING'">
          <span class="md-margin__right--xs md-padding__left--l inline-block text-divider">
            {{ selectedAlerts.length }} Job(s) Selected
          </span>
  <button md-button [size]="28"
          aria-label="Cancel" class="md-margin__horizontal--s" color="red" (click)="cancel()">
    Cancel
  </button>

</ng-container>
```

Currently, I am only able to check for the first item in the array:

```
*ngIf="selectedAlerts.length && selectedStatus[0] === 'PENDING'"
```

How do I check it for the whole `selectedStatus` array items?

Comment: Write a function in the ts file where you iterate through all the items and set the flag true when all are pending. Let the ngIf be based on that flag variable.

Comment: You can add function in your *ngIf `*ngIf="checkSelectedItemsStatus()"` and in that function you can return status based on selected items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do your logic in the `ts` file (a method to be called in the template)

and to answer your question, you can check all the items in an array by using one of the builtin array methods:

for example:

check if all items are pending:

```js
selectedStatus.every(item => item === 'PENDING')
```

check if at least one items is pending:

```js
selectedStatus.some(item => item === 'PENDING')
```

for more info check these documentations:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Array includes() method to check if any of your array items contains the string 'PENDING' like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedAlerts.length && selectedStatus.includes('PENDING')">
```